# Some errors with a little document

Tags: errors, pdftex, warnings, acronyms

I have some errors with my paper in LaTeX, and I don't understand how to fix the problems :

The first is :

> ```
> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the sa
> me identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
> <to be read again>
> ```

On google, I found that I have to add the option `pdfpagelabels`, but I still get this error.

Then I have an other error :

> ```
> <to be read again> 
>                    \relax 
> l.37 \chapter
>              {Introduction} [1]
> ```

Just after the previous one. This one I have no idea how to fix the problem. I don't know why there is this eroor.

And the last one is a warning :

> ```
> Overfull \hbox (16.278pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 43--44
> \T1/cmr/m/n/10 I did my in-tern-ship in a lab-o-ra-tory in Nantes called [][]
> ```

I use the package `acronym`, but unfortunately the acronym is too long, and so I have the warning that a paragraph is too wide. Can fix it, and how ?

I give you the original document :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%\usepackage{pdftex}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\title{Prediction of Parallel Speed-ups for Las Vegas Algorithms}
\author{François Thiré}
\date{\today}

\pagestyle{headings}

%Acronyms
\acrodef{lina}[Laboratoire d'Informatique de Nantes Altantique]{LINA}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section*{Acknowledgement}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{\acl{lina}}

I did my internship in a laboratory in Nantes calle \ac{lina}\footnote{Computer sciences laboratory of Nantes Atlantique}. The following      
words will present this laboratory. 
\begin{appendix}
\chapter{Bibliography}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, your file works for me, but only after I make each character ASCII (not UTF8, your name is `Francois Thire` in my test).  (Also removing the relevant packages `inputenc` and `fontenc`.)

Comment: Your file compiles without any problem here; only an overfull-box warning. Are you sure all your packages are up to date?

Comment: With “error” you mean “warning” in the first two cases, right? They actually seem to belong to the same warning. It goes away when `\maketitle` is omitted but I have no idea why.

Comment: Inded, Latex write a PDF file. But I still don't know why I get these errors.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you first try to write [a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).